# SQL - controlling what columns get returned in a join

Tags: sql

So I have two tables.

Table 1 has 10 columns, Col1 to Col10

Table 2 has 8 columns, Col1 to Col8

If I want to do a join and return all of table 1 but just one column of table2 is there a way to do that aside from specifying in the Select part of the query which columns I want to return?

```
Select Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2.........Table2.Col1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use * to indicate all fields:

```
Select Table1.*, Table2.ColX
from ...
```